# overflow menu is not showing in fragment

Tags: android

```
    snapshot


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0uHw.png

please help how to show overflow menu in fragment.my code below

this is my fragment code:.,,.,.,.,.,.,.,




  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


this is my menu xml.,.,.,.,.,.,.




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/addContactItemId"
        android:title="@string/addContact"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
```

please help me.thanks in advance.i have saw some tutorial where overflow menu created by default but it was for activity but i am trying overflow menu in fragment.please help

Comment: Fix your code so users can understand it and help.

Comment: share the code from the activity whose hosting the fragment for the methods onOptionsItemSelected or onCreateOptionsMenu if you are using those methods

Answer (score 1):

Do you have setHasOptionsMenu(true) in your code somewhere for this particular fragment you want the menu in?

Something like...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Your fragment must be told that it has an options menu otherwise it won't try to inflate one.

Documentation: [setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

Comment: yess. setHasOptionsMenu(true); this has in on create

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: Link your activities call to: "public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)" (that is if you are calling it at all)

Comment: the activity that is hosting your fragment